# How to Insert into remote table using Linked server withint Transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linked-server

My Linked server is setup correctly , I am able to perform below query.

> INSERT INTO [RemoteServer].[Table]
>   SELECT * FROM [LocalServer].[Table]

However when I do the same thing **within transaction**

> BEGIN TRAN
>    INSERT INTO [RemoteServer].[Table]
>    SELECT * FROM [LocalServer].[Table]
>   COMMIT TRAN

I get Errors like

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked
>   server "66.70.123.202" returned
>   message "No transaction is active.".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   The operation could not be performed
>   because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for
>   linked server "66.70.123.202" was
>   unable to begin a distributed
>   transaction.

Comment: See: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/msg/127255ab5a3a1fe0

Comment: According this they are saying I should be able to PING Both servers from each other...but how can i do that ? They are on different domain.

Comment: So at the end I am not doing my process in transaction. I am recovering my data inside try and catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if MS DTC service is running on both servers and it is configured correctly to allow distribured queries.

Comment: Yes MS DTC runs fine. I am able to query and insert data into remote server without begin transaction. I have "no auth. required" set and allowing all in and out traffic from MS DTC.

Comment: Are your firewall configured to allow MS DTC?